# Gmail & Google App Scripts - Apply label based on star colors

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Currently I am just using the search bar `has:red-bang` but I would prefer to apply labels to `has:red-bang` and `has:yellow-bang` so I can see a count to see how many unread emails are found in that label.

When I use Google's filter options, and I set the rule to has:red-bang, it does not work.

Is is possible to achieve this using Google App Scripts instead?

**Logic:**

- When email has:red-bang apply label "High Priority", mark as unread.
- When email has:yellow-bang apply label "Low Priority", mark as unread.

This way I can open my email each day, and click on High Priority to respond to all those emails first. Then if I have time, then I will click on Low Priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE:

I played around this and was able to find through the Developer Console the following information:

### Gmail Superstar labels are formatted in the following:

- l:^ss_cr = has:red-bang
- l:^ss_cy = has:yellow-bang
- l:^ss_cb = has:blue-info

So with the following code sample, I was able to use `GmailApp.search()` with the following superstar label queries above. This does seem to be undocumented as of the moment.

**Here is the code:**

```
    function myFunction() {

  //Gets the label names. Make sure this is already created on Gmail. 
  var rlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('High Priority');
  var ylabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Less Priority');

  //Applies the label 'High Priority' whenever messages are found with red-bang
  var redbang = GmailApp.search('l:^ss_cr');
  redbang.forEach(x => x.addLabel(rlabel).markUnread());
  //Applies the label 'Less Priority' whenever messages are found with yellow-bang
  var yellowstar = GmailApp.search('l:^ss_cy');
  yellowstar.forEach(y => y.addLabel(ylabel).markUnread());

  Logger.log(redbang);
  Logger.log(yellowstar);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Diego. I tested all the variations, and determined that they all work except for red-bang and yellow-bang for some strange reason. When using Yellow-bang & red-bang, I noticed both colors would appear in High Priority and both in Less Priority. Here are all the options that work with the script above:

yellow-star: l:^ss_sy   |   Blue Star: l:^ss_sb   |   Red Star: l:^ss_sr   |   Orange Star: l:^ss_so   |   Green Star: l:^ss_sg   |   Purple Star: l:^ss_sp   |   Blue Info: l:^ss_cb   |   Orange Guillemet: l:^ss_co   |   Green Check: l:^ss_cg   |   Purple Question: l:^ss_cp