# Google Apps Script - Remove Label IFF Star Removed from Thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have been using a Google Apps Script to apply gmail labels based on the color of stars I apply to a message (e.g., Red Star = Follow Up, etc.)

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72694138/18448481) to help build the script, which is running successfully, as below.

```
function myFunction() {
//Gets the label names.
   var rLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Follow Up');

//Applies the label 'Follow Up' whenever messages are found with redStar
   var redStar = GmailApp.search('l:^ss_sr');
   redStar.forEach(x => x.addLabel(rLabel).markRead());
}
```

As a next step I wanted to remove the label once I had actioned the email, which I achieved by adding a search query and `forEach` loop in the function.

```
function myFunction() {
//Gets the label names.
   var rLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Follow Up');

//Applies the label 'Follow Up' whenever messages are found with redStar
   var redStar = GmailApp.search('l:^ss_sr');
   redStar.forEach(x => x.addLabel(rLabel).markRead());
   
//Removes Follow Up Label when redStar is removed
   var labelFollow = GmailApp.search('label:follow-up -l:^ss_sr');
   labelFollow.forEach(x => x.removeLabel(rLabel));
}
```

From what I understand though, the "`-`"operator in the `GmailApp.search()` query matches if *any message in a thread* does not have the specified star, instead of if *all messages in the thread* do not have the specified star. So, while this works flawlessly for single-message threads, as soon as there is a second message in the conversation (e.g., a reply), it registers that one of the messages does not have the `red-star` and removes the label from the whole thread.

I am unable to do a blanket `is:starred` operator because I might switch the star types (e.g., from `Red-Star` to `Blue-Info`, in which case I would like to remove the 'Follow Up' label and apply my 'Important Information' label instead.

Is there a way that I can only remove the label IFF there are no matching messages with the specified star on any of the messages in the thread? (i.e., IFF none of the messages have a `Red-star`, then remove the 'Follow Up' label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't very efficient (it might time out if there are a lot of threads with that label), but you should be able to generate the list of "no red star" threads subtractively, by getting a list of all threads with the follow-up label, then getting the search result for red-starred threads in that label, and removing these from the first list.  e.g. something like this:

```
var rLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Follow Up');
let followUpThreads = rLabel.getThreads()
// Make a map of {id1:true, id2:true, ...} 
// for all thread id's that are red-starred
let redStarThreadIdsMap = Object.fromEntries(
  GmailApp.search('label:follow-up l:^ss_sr')
    .map(t => [t.getId(), true])
)
followUpThreads.forEach(thread =>
{
  if (!redStarThreadIdsMap[thread.getId()])
  {
    thread.removeLabel(rLabel)
  }
})
```

Comment: This worked for me - I'm not sure what the threshold will be for timing out, but for now it seems to be running without issue.